# C++ error LNK2019

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to create string variable `string time` and it should look like `14:58`.
I created function

```
string SetTime() {
long double h = (long double)(rand()%25);
long double m = (long double)(rand()%60);

string hour = to_string(h);
string minutes = (m <= 9 ? "0" : "" ) + to_string(m);

string time = hour + ":" + minutes;
return time;
}
```

but when I try to use it

```
string str = SetNumber();
cout << str;
```

I get
`error LNK2019: link to unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl SetNumber(void)" (?SetNumber@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) in _wmain`

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you mixing up SetNumber/SetTime function calls?

Comment: Yes, I mixed up two functions, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is called `SetTime` while you're calling `SetNumber`. The linker cannot find the definition of `SetNumber`. It is interesting that you are getting a linker error rather than a compiler error. It means that you've declared `SetNumber`.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, so stupid mistake, I tried to use other my function.

Comment: with a messed up incremental build it can happen that the compiler (VC++ in this case) thinks it does not need to recompile the called code, and then the linker cannot link the caller code to the old code. A full rebuild should resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

you should call SetTime, not SetNumber

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, so stupid mistake, I tried to use other my function.